# Mac's "System Preferences" asked me for iCloud password, Mac password, and my iPad's password — is this normal?

Tags: mac, icloud, security, password, system-settings

The *System Preferences* app on my Mac displayed a message saying I needed to provide password to log into my iCloud account, otherwise some services would not work. I complied.

Then System Preferences asked for my Mac's startup password. I complied.

Lastly, System Preferences asked for my iPad's password, using the name of my iPad. I complied.

Now I'm getting a bit worried. I did verify that it was the System Preferences app asking for these passwords.

Is this normal behavior? I do not recall every being prompted this way.

Comment: So you entered the passwords THEN got worried? Had you done an update?

Comment: It **sounds** like iCloud wanted you to sign in to do iCloud-type things, probably one of those occasional sign-in things that happens now and then. I would imagine you could have cancelled that. I have, on occasion, gotten requests for this or that iOS device on my Mac so the other two requests seem normal *in my experience.*

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing on my iPad. (See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/457656/489896) see the comments on the question for more info and maybe find an answer.