# Update Apple ID Settings recurrent warning

Tags: ipad, icloud, security, apple-id

It's now been the *5th time I get this alert since the beginning of the week*! It shows a notification badge in Settings saying that I have to :

> **Update Apple ID Settings**

I'm connected to my usual iCloud account / Apple ID and haven't done any modifications to the related parameters since quite a long time (1-2 years). Before, I was prompted to give my Apple ID password about every 6 months. But now, since I updated to **iPadOS 16.2**, it's almost every day!

[image]

When I click on "Continue" (Apple ID is after "Enter the password for : ") :

[image]

I haven't given my password for the alert show in the screenshots yet and haven't noticed anything suspicious in my recent files or iCloud account / Apple ID settings.

**Edit** : I tried to log out/log in to my Apple ID manually but the same alert showed up again. Also, I tried logging out, force-restarting my iPad and logging in again but still no luck, the alert wasn't here on login but about 30-45 minutes later, it reappeared.

*Note* : This behaviour was also noticed on my iPhone, connected to the same Apple ID. I did the same tests as explained above but no avail here too.

**Is this legit or is it a malware or something harmful trying to get my password? If it's a malware, how to get rid of it?**

Comment: I can confirm this isn't malware - it's normal for Settings to prompt. However you're correct it shouldn't do it this frequently.

Comment: Try logging out of iCloud manually, then login again and see if the problem recurs.

Comment: @IconDaemon I just did what you asked me to do : The badge asking to update Apple ID Settings disappeared (obviously) when I was logged out but it reappeared when I logged it again. (It's still the same one as when I asked the question, haven't given my password yet)

Comment: So, once you logged back in successfully, the password prompt is still appearing? I was hoping that by deliberately logging out, it would reset something, but I guess it didn't work. Next thing to try is to shutdown your iPad and restart it. Login to your Apple ID when requested. See [this page](https://www.imobie.com/iphone-problems/apple-id-sign-in-request.htm) for other things to try. Do you have other Apple devices which are also using your Apple ID?

Comment: @IconDaemon Thank you for you comment, what I did after seeing you comment one hour ago is : log out of iCloud account, restart my iPad, reconnect to iCloud account. This worked but now, about 45 minutes later, another request appeared! I am also using the same Apple ID with my iPhone and it does the same thing.